# ag search results has corrupted messages in emacs

Tags: emacs, ag

Recently my ag search results have started returning corrupted results like this:

```
[[?25h^[[0G^[[?25h^[[0Gapp/config/development.coffee:49:33:#
```

I am unsure as to why this has suddenly started happening.

Comment: Seems like ANSI colour codes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your context is exactly, but FWIW if you add `--vimgrep` as an argument to `ag` then you shouldn't get color codes in the response.